# WooCommerce Update Triggers an error notice About Wrap_Before variable

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just updated a few plugins for a clients site that I host on flywheel (WP Engine now). I updated WooCommerce and I get this error: `Notice: Undefined variable: wrap_before in /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php on line 25 Notice: Undefined variable: before in /www/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/global/breadcrumb.php on line 29`

I have not edited or changed any core files in the global folder ever so I am a little confused as to why this suddenly has happened. It worked perfectly on a local computer with exact same settings after the update, its just the staging site that throws this error.